# Where condition to filter SQL query to the first day of each month

Tags: sql, filter, where-clause

I have a SQL query that contains multiple records for each day of the month, over a number of years.
Can someone help me out to filter the query that will only return the first day of each month.
And also as soon as a new month starts, it is automatically added to the filter?
Really appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: Please conduct the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), find an implementation that fits your use case, then make an earnest attempt. Return with any issues with table schema, sample data, and attempted SQL code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tag your backend but most databases have the same or similar datepart() function for extracting parts of date. ie:

```
select * from myTable where date_part('day', theDateColumn) = 1;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified (as noted). But at least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, you can use it for postgreSQL, and also MS SQL server removing quotes and underscore. Check your backend's documentation for the function that does the same. Idea is to get the day of month as a number.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can query a date using the LIKE statement.

Assuming that you have a field named 'randomDate' in 'mytable' where you want to perform the query, and that this is a DATE type, you could do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( id int, randomDate date);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, randomDate) 
VALUES
(1, '2022-12-01'),
(2, '2022-12-02');

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE randomDate LIKE '%01';
```

Comment: Do never use string functions on dates. One of multiple risks is that you don't know what is the day and what is the month when doing this. There are very useful date functions, so use them.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.